# What is the 'group' aesthetic doing here

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I was reading the gganimate reference and came across the group aesthetics. I don't understand what it does in the particular context and there's also a statement in the code about its usage that I don't get. Here's the statement:

> Object permanence
> transition_states uses the group aesthetic of each layer to identify which rows in the input data correspond to the same graphic element and will therefore define which elements will turn into each other between states. The group aesthetic, if not set, will be calculated from the interaction of all discrete aesthetics in the layer (excluding label), so it is often better to set it explicitly when animating, to make sure your data is interpreted in the right way. If the group aesthetic is not set, and no discrete aesthetics exists then all rows will have the same group. If the group aesthetic is not unique in each state, then rows will be matched first by group and then by index. Unmatched rows will appear/disappear, potentially using an enter or exit function.

Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

iris$group <- seq_len(nrow(iris))
anim1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Width, group=group)) +
  geom_point()+  
 labs(title = "{closest_state}") +
 transition_states(Species, transition_length = 3, state_length = 1) +
  enter_fade() +
exit_fade()
anim1
```

Can someone explain in simpler words what the text mean, usage of group in the code, and why if group is removed the function or the plot doesnt work the same way.

Comment: I know what 'group' aesthetic does, but I need to know why does removing group leads to failure in production of the desired plot.